# Wacom Bamboo tablet drawing while hovering with pen

Tags: tablet, pen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wacom Bamboo Fun pen draws even while hovering](https://superuser.com/questions/6894/wacom-bamboo-fun-pen-draws-even-while-hovering)

I have a new Wacom Bamboo Model MTE-450 tablet with pen. It's buttons are not broken. I have reinstalled the driver four times and updated them every time.

When I use my pen for drawing, it makes a line without actually touching the tablet.

I'm aware of the other question about this, but it did not address my particular concern.

Comment: Just like any online place. Shouting is frowned on. You will make Unicorns cry. Which is sad :'(

Comment: While I'm no expert on Wacom hardware, I guess someone who is might need to know which OS you use, and it would likely be easier if you linked to the question you speak of and told us why the answers there weren't satisfactory.

Answer (score 4):

it could be the nib is stuck in the on/clicked position. Pull the nib out and let sit for a few hours, see [Wacom Bamboo Fun pen draws even while hovering](https://superuser.com/questions/6894/wacom-bamboo-fun-pen-draws-even-while-hovering/165382#165382). Since your tablet is new it is still under warranty, take advantage of this if pulling the nib does not work.