# Huion h610 Pen Hovering And Still Drawing?

Tags: tablet, drawing, pen

I've had my Huion h610 for almost a year now and it was working perfectly up until today. I don't know why it started to act up. I was just finishing up some line work and all of a sudden it starting drawing with me just **hovering**. Now, I just thought that my nib might be out of whack so I replaced the nib but nothing changed. I use the drawing software Manga Studio 5, but I know that it's not in the software because it acts this way on websites and just on my computer in general. And when I do finally click down on the pen it simply just stops and spazzes, clicking on and off repeatedly. It's frustrating to say the least and very hard to draw. If anyone has a good solution for this it's be much appreciated. I'm going to let my pen sit out overnight with no nib since I've heard that it helps sometimes. I'm hoping it will. If it doesn't though, I think that I might just have to look into getting a new pen or something...Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the advice of dismantling the stylus from http://superuser.com/questions/6894/wacom-bamboo-fun-pen-draws-even-while-hovering ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using these methods to fix your pen:

- Replace/change nibs (pen tips)
- changing the battery (AAA)
- letting it rest for awhile
- Resetting (taking out the USB cord and reinserting it) the whole system (pen and tablet)

I have a h420 too. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

i finally found a way to fix the problem, you probably dropped it as i did as well, my huion pen had been broken for about 3 weeks already, and i found the most simple way to fix it drawing while hovering, and all problems altogether. Im serious

heres the link to the archive, i didnt want to re-write it over again, scroll to the bottom of the page and click on page 2, that's when you'll see my post from J0shuu, please read it and follow

https://web.archive.org/web/20171211141044/https://osu.ppy.sh/forum/t/341683/start=15

> Unscrew the top. An indented crack should be present as people drop it, lift up the indent with a pin so its even, (its fine if you break a bit off)
>
> Then place the tip in and the pressure should be showing fine when hovering, test on the software, if feint lines show, adjust the pressure sensitivity a bit to the right until it dissapears. Hope it helps you, since the first post is 2 years old, dont think you care

This fixed the hovering problem, put it into its normal state, and the light started to work properly when you touch the pen on the board

Comment: Please try to contain most important information in your post. Read more about posting link-only answers [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251613/2420535)

Comment: Ditto.  This post will be here for years and might suffer link-rot.  So please write a brief on what is at that link.  Meanwhile:  Welcome to Superuser.  You should take the tour at https://superuser.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Comment: And... link rot set in.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into your settings and put the pen pressure all the way up it fixes it. So hopefully it works. I don't understand the problem, I just know not to drop it now.

Answer (score 1):

I unscrewed the top part of the pen (near the nib) along with the battery chamber. When I put screwed the three parts back together, the pen was working fine! My assumption is that when I dropped the pen (which I unfortunately have done quite often,) the screw tracks got knocked out of place.

Hope this solution helps!

Answer (score -1):

(hi this is the same person who answered awhile ago)
Another thing you could do is to try replacing your pen, if you'd prefer

Answer (score -1):

Don't change the pen, you know why? Because i just did the same thing as you. I have a huion and eventualky it was working fine until the next day that i tried to used it. The pen didn't react to the tablet and it was still drawing but like turning off and on. So, i thought. Oh okay, maybe it's just the nib! But no, and that's when i bought a new pen, and when i did and put it on the tablet. Nothing, it still the same! So it mught not actually be the pen. It's the tablet. Because i just bought a new pen and it the same result. So i suggest you buy another tablet or try to update the drivers or the tablet program.