# Wacom Bamboo preference file (Solved in the past, but having the same issue now)

Tags: bamboo

A few months ago a friend of mine gave me a Wacom Bamboo drawing tablet. He said it was old (from 2009) and wasn't sure if it still worked. He also gave me the CD with the driver. I installed everything and it was working. There was one problem. By hovering the pen on the tablet it would start clicking/drawing.

I tried changing the pressure slider but it didn't work.

A few days after I found a solution by editing some values on a preference file (I think it was an xml file). By lowering the value I could use it normally.
Now I lost that file because I changed computer.

Where can I find it?

Comment: What file did you modify?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/6894/wacom-bamboo-fun-pen-draws-even-while-hovering?rq=1

Comment: Is it perhaps AppGestures.xml you're looking for, which on my computer is located in C:\Program Files\Tablet\Pen\ ?