# Wacom Intuos Pro pen writes while hovering

Tags: drawing, pen

If I start drawing/writing then the pen often keeps writing while being lifted off and moved to the next position where I actually want it to draw. This makes the tablet completely unusable. It's similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/6894/wacom-bamboo-fun-pen-draws-even-while-hovering) question, but another type of Wacom tablet and pen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to simply remove the tip from the pen, tap the empty pen to the table a couple of times, brush dust off the tip and reinsert the tip. There was a tip remover included with my tablet, along with a selection of tips that could also be tried if a certain tip just won't work. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after dropping the pen for my veikk tablet. I opened it up with a pair of pliers and carefully removed the electronics. The stylus tip plugs into a little metallic cylinder that move back and forth in an inductive coil when you press on the tip, this is how it senses the force. I unscrewed the inductor from the electronics bit (had to desolder the inductor leads first). The metallic cylinder is very brittle and crystalline, and mine was broken in half. It was a clean break, so I glued it back together with a drop of super glue. I used 220 grit sandpaper to clean up the tiny bit of super glue overflow so that the metal bit could still slide easily back and forth in the inductor (and resoldered the inductor leads) You can screw and unscrew the inductive part in order to tune the sensitivity, so I screw that in and out and practiced drawing on my tablet until it seemed about what it was before. I reassembled the pen halfway (just putting the electronics into the front part of the pen) and found that it was a little off once assembled, so I opened it back up, tweaked how far in the inductor was screwed in (did this a few times) and once I was satisfied I put the back end onto the pen, and it's been working since. I guess be very careful with these pens, I didn't realized there was a little metallic crystalline piece in there.